# TextView not displaying EditText string on user input

Tags: android, textview, gettext, tostring

Heres the scenario:

A user enters a team name into an `EditText` field, the text of that is then the new name of a TextView (using `setText()`). If the user has not entered anything into the `EditText` field yet, the `setText()` will be the same text property, as declared in the xml file (so basically the default).

So far I have this code and it is not working. When I type anything into the `EditText` field and click on something else, the `TextView` does not change.

```
public void teamNameChange(View view)
{
    TextView team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
    EditText team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);

    if (team1Name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        team1NameScore.setText("Team 1 Score:");
    } else {
        team1NameScore.setText("" +team1Name);
    }
}
```

Any idea why the text isn't changing?

**EDIT- FINAL WORKING CODE:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
    final EditText team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);

    team1Name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String newString = team1Name.getText().toString();
            if (!hasFocus) {
                team1NameScore.setText("" + newString);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Where do you call `teamNameChange()`?

Comment: Oh whoops... I didn't call it anywhere. I tried it in my onCreate() method before, but that didn't work. Where should I put this?

Comment: @Collin your code, your logic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do something like this

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            textView.setText("changed");
        }
    }
});
```

Knowing that, of course, editText1 & textView1 are horrible variable names.

Comment: final TextView team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
final EditText team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);   
Both need to be inside the onCreate method

Comment: I had to add "String newString = team1Name.getText().toString();" because it would grab the element entirely and display a bunch of random android code as the setText(). 

Edited the original post to show how the final answer works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well you basically have to ways to do it when a button is click or when you type something to change the text dynamically both of them are pretty simple. Here are both ways of doing it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final TextView team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
final EditText team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);
Button btn1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = team1Name.getText().toString();
            team1NameScore.setText(text);

        }
    });



team1Name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }// do nothing

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        } // do nothing

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = team1Name.getText().toString();
            team1NameScore.setText(text);
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: I don't have a button in my app, I want this to change the text dynamically. Could you give me that example code?

Comment: I edited my answer so now the text is changed when you type something

Comment: +1 for you, I appreciate the response but above question had a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have you Member variables be final, and they should be initialized int the OnCreate method. You should call teamNameChange(View v) where you are listening for the change of the team name.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private EditText editText;
private TextView textView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
    team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);
    team1Name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                /*team1NameScore.setText("changed");*/
                teamNameChange(v);
            }
        }
    });

}
```